# How to increment group numbers in a settings file?

Tags: windows, text-editing, string, string-manipulation, text-manipulation

I have an application with a settings file (.ini) that contains data in the common format:

```
[group1]
foo=bar
bar=baz
...


[group2]
foo=bar
bar=baz
...


...


[group500]
foo=bar
bar=baz
...
```

where the `foo=bar` and `bar=baz` can be any strings, and there can be from 1-9 declarations in each group.

I now need to add `[group150]`, and increment all the later groups by one integer number.

For example, the current `[group150]` needs to be changed to `[group151]`, and the current `[group151]` needs to be changed to `[group152]`.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this task without manually editing hundreds of `[groupXXX]` section headings?

Solutions using Windows 7 itself, batch files, PowerShell, or any free software (Notepad++, LibreOffice, etc.) are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Notepad++ solution**

1. Add the Python Script plugin in Notepad++
2. After adding it, click Plugins -> Python Script -> New Script
3. Give the script a name, use the following code:

```
import re

number = -1
def calculate(match):
    global number
    number = int(match.group(0))
    if number >= 150:
        number += 1
    return str(number)

editor.rereplace('(?<=group)\d+', calculate)
```

4. Save the script. Open your file.
5. Click Plugins -> Python Script -> Scripts. Select the script you just created.
6. When the script finishes running, add the new group 150.

Comment: Clever!  Upvoted!  Thank you so much Reddy!  Do you happen to also be fluent in LuaScript?  If so, I would love to see the same technique written in LuaScript.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Unfortunately, I am not fluent in LuaScript.

Comment: No problem, maybe I'll learn more LuaScript soon, or someone else will already know it and post.  Thank you again for your great answer!